# How did I get two anglers?

Tags: terraria-mobile

While killing King Slime, I noticed in the chat it had said '||||| the angler has arrived!' But I still had one before that. I found him asleep on the right side of the world, and saw something wrong.[image]

It shows that I have an angler where I am, and one back at home. Why, and how, did this happen?

Comment: Bryce is the name of my first angler (The one in the house) if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug appearing on mobile only.

> If the Angler is killed, the game doesn't know whether to spawn him in
>   a house or respawn him on the beach, so it does both. This can result
>   in getting 2 Anglers.

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler)